# Convert a text field to a selection field drop-down lists

Tags: php, html, wordpress

the following code shows a text field for the user to write their city, I would like to convert that text field into a selection field with a drop-down list. My knowledge in php is very basic, I appreciate you can help me.

The code is located in a PHP template of a user profile.

```
    <?php
global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();
$userID             = $current_user->ID;
$user_login         = $current_user->user_login;
$state       = get_the_author_meta( 'user_state' , $userID );
?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">  
  <div class="couple-profile-main-block dashboard-box">
    <form id="user-profile" class="ajax-auth form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="status"></div>  
      <?php wp_nonce_field('ajax-user-profile-nonce', 'security'); ?>    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
 
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4"><label><?php esc_html_e('State','theme');?>*</label></div> 
                  
                  <div class="col-sm-8"><input class="form-control" id="state" name="state" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($state);?>"></div> 
                
                </div>                                                          
            </div>        
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8"><button id="couple-profile-on" class="btn btn-pink"><?php esc_html_e('Update Profile','theme');?></button></div> 
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to switch out that text-input to a select input - check out https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

In your case, something like this should replace where the text input is.

```
<select class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
    <option value=“State1” <?php if ($state == “State1”) echo “selected”; ?>>State 1</option>

<option value=“State2” <?php if ($state == “State2”) echo “selected”; ?>>State 2</option>

<option value=“State3” <?php if ($state == “State3”) echo “selected”; ?>>State 3</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Hi @James Amner Your code shows the select field correctly but when I press the update profile button, the option that the user selected is not saved.

Comment: Saving the form will need to have a form-handler. Did the previous form work? If the previous form did work then this code should work just as before as long as the `name` for the `<select>` is the same as the `<input>` field. If not, building a form-handler is a bit beyond the scope of a stack-overflow Q&A. I can recommend something like https://wpmudev.com/blog/handling-form-submissions/ to help learn how this works.